# Duplicating an object in array of objects at specified position

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I've read a few answers on similar questions but they didn't seem to match my problem exactly. I have an array of objects. I'm trying to create a duplicate of an item(s) and insert it at a certain position, but it doesn't work and when I am looking at the array in the debugger I'm seeing that the very first item of the element now has priKey = 0.

I'm suspecting that I'm running into the problem of the referencing the same item and not making a true clone and that's why I'm ending up with the first element priKey = 0.

Before inserting new Items I have 26 items in the elementsToInsert:

```js
{priKey: 170, internlPo: 7, department: "RETAIL    ", category: "WINTERGEAR", item: "BOOTS-SALO"}

{priKey: 171, internlPo: 7, department: "RETAIL    ", category: "WINTERGEAR", item: "BOOTS-SALO"}

{priKey: 172, internlPo: 7, department: "RETAIL    ", category: "WINTERGEAR", item: "BOOTS-SALO"}
```

My objects have more properties, I'm showing just a few.

Here is my current code and I'm trying to figure out where exactly the problem lies:

```js
/**
     * Copy line item (either all matrix items for this itemId or just that matrix item)
     * */
    purchaseOrdersCrudController.prototype.copyLineItem = function (lineItem, index, copyAll) {
        
        const self = this;
        
        let elementsToInsert = [];
        _.forEach(self.model.lineItems, function (value, key) {
            if (value.itemId === lineItem.itemId) {

                if (copyAll || key === index) {                    
                    elementsToInsert.push(value); // new elements to insert                                      
                }                
            }
        });

        let i, startPos;
        let len = elementsToInsert.length;
        startPos = index + len;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            elementsToInsert[i].priKey = 0;
            elementsToInsert[i].qtyRcvd = 0;
            self.model.lineItems.splice(startPos + i, 0, elementsToInsert[i]); // Insert new element
        }

        // Re-number
        let rn = 0;
        len = self.model.lineItems.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
            if (self.model.lineItems[i].itemId === lineItem.itemId) {
                rn++;
                if (self.model.lineItems[i].inventId === 0) {
                    self.model.lineItems[key].rowNumber = 1;
                }
                else {
                    self.model.lineItems[key].rowNumber = rn; // Make sure the row number is in sequence
                }
            }
        };
        this.form.$setDirty();
    }
```

The idea of that code is to duplicate an item. If in my interface I'm clicking on the "header" row, I want to copy all items where itemId equals the selected item itemId and insert them all after the last item for that particular itemId (I may have several). If I click on a "regular" row, I just want to duplicate that line and insert it right below my current line and re-number the remaining items for that itemId. I'm struggling to make that code to work and not seeing where is my mistake.

Comment: please add som data before inserting/updateing and after updating with indices or id.

Comment: I've updated my question and posted the objects I'm trying to insert (this is what I have in the elementsToInsert array right before the second loop - I copied a few relevant properties but I have more properties of these objects - they don't really matter for the purpose of my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, as I suspected the problem was in cloning the object properly. This is my current code which does what I need (it seems in my quick test). I'd appreciate suggestions to improve it:

```js
purchaseOrdersCrudController.prototype.copyLineItem = function (lineItem, index, copyAll) {
        
        const self = this;
        
        let elementsToInsert = [];
        let newElement = {};
        _.forEach(self.model.lineItems, function (value, key) {
            if (value.itemId === lineItem.itemId) {

                if (copyAll || key === index) {  
                    newElement = Object.assign({}, value);
                    newElement.priKey = 0;
                    newElement.qtyRcvd = 0;
                    elementsToInsert.push(newElement); // new elements to insert                                      
                }                
            }
        });

        let i, startPos;
        let len = elementsToInsert.length;
        startPos = index + len;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           
            self.model.lineItems.splice(startPos + i, 0, elementsToInsert[i]); // Insert new element
        }

        // Re-number
        let rn = 0;
        len = self.model.lineItems.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
            if (self.model.lineItems[i].itemId === lineItem.itemId) {
                rn++;
                if (self.model.lineItems[i].inventId === 0) {
                    self.model.lineItems[i].rowNumber = 1;
                }
                else {
                    self.model.lineItems[i].rowNumber = rn; // Make sure the row number is in sequence
                }
            }
        };
        this.form.$setDirty();
    }
```